# How to find all week numbers that are first week of month in a year python

Tags: python, django, date, time, calendar

I want to create a event that falls on Sunday of every first week of months.

This is what I am doing for a particular week number which is first week of `june` to get date:

```
from datetime import datetime
myDate = "2017 22 0"
# here `2017` is year, `22` is week number and `0` =sunday is week day
datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y %W %w")

#output...
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 0, 0)
```

So I need a list of all week numbers that are first week of month so I can loop on it and get desire dates.

**Adding More information**

I want a method which return list of week numbers which are first week of month where first week means week has first sunday.

```
def get_week_number(year=2017, day=0):
   #day 0 means sunday
   ...
   ...
   return [1, 5, 9, 13, 18, 22, ...]
```

Comment: How do you define the first week of a month? The week with the first day? The first week that has 4 or more days of the month? The week with the first sunday? Something else?

Comment: @RuuddeJong The week with the first sunday.

Comment: Also for week numbers there is ambiguity, because you need to define what the first week of the year is. And you have to define on what day a week starts. There are different conventions. In Europe and according to ISO standard, e.g. a week starts on Monday. As far as I know, in the US a week commonly starts on Sunday. The first week of the year can also be defined in several ways. The most common ones are: the week with January 1, the week with the first Thursday (ISO standard), or the first complete week.

Comment: Once you decide on what the first week of the year is, you can simply take the `timedelta` between the first sunday in the month and the start of the first week in the year and divide that by 7 to get the week number (tbut take care of one-offs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a loop through the months, then got the first Sunday (starting at month's 1<sup>st</sup> and moving to the next day until a Sunday is found), then got the week-of-year of the date found:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

# dayofweek: Sunday=0, Monday=1 and so on
def get_week_number(year=2017, dayofweek=0):
    weeks = []

    for month in range(1, 13):
        # get first Sunday of month
        d = date(year, month, 1)
        while(d.weekday() != dayofweek):
            d = d.replace(day=d.day + 1)

        # isocalendar()[1] is the week-of-year field
        weeks.append(d.isocalendar()[1])

    return weeks

print(get_week_number(2017, 0))
```

The result, though, is different from what you expect:

```
[1, 6, 10, 14, 18, 23, 27, 32, 36, 40, 45, 49]
```

I also tried with `weeks.append(int(d.strftime("%W")))` but it gives the same results - I'm using Python 3.5.2 and [a week is defined as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar):

> The ISO year consists of 52 or 53 full weeks, and where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday. This is called week number 1, and the ISO year of that Thursday is the same as its Gregorian year.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

(Edited, because of error in weekday numbering)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> june1 = datetime.datetime(2017,6,1)
>>> june1
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 0, 0)
>>> june1_weekday = june1.weekday()
>>> if june1_weekday < 6:  # 6 indicates Sunday
        first_sunday_in_june = june1 + datetime.timedelta(days=6-june1_weekday)
else:
        first_sunday_in_june = june1


>>> print(first_sunday_in_june)
2017-06-04 00:00:00
```

Assuming you want ISO weeknumbers, you can then use the `isocalendar()` method. This gives a tuple `(year, weeknumber, weekday)`. This uses the convention that weeks start with Monday, and the first week of the year is the first week with at least four days in the year (or in other words, the week with the first Thursday).

```
>>> first_sunday_in_june.isocalendar()
(2017, 22, 7)
```

If you have another convention for first-day-of-the-week or first-week-of-the-year, you will have to brew your own function to get the week number.

Use the above method in a loop over the months, and you can create the desired list with week numbers.

Comment: I asked for list of week numbers in a particular year that are first week. i.e for year 2017 output will be [1, 5, 9, 13, 18, 22, ...]

Comment: Your post seems to indicate that you want to find the Sundays in the first week, and you defined the first week as the week with the first Sunday. I showed you how to find the first Sunday without using the week number. So you don't need week numbers for this. Week numbers are ambiguous anyway, because you would have to define what the first week of the year is. ISO and MS disagree on that.

Comment: Apologies if i was not clear, Is there any way to find out what i am looking for?